# Win32 php fsockopen - getaddrinfo failed

Tags: windows, php, сокет

Скачал php-5.6.0-Win32-VC11-x86.zip, пытаюсь использовать как cgi. Не работает fsockopen(), выдает ошибку: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Этот хост неизвестен. Функция dns_get_record("php.net") Возвращает пустой результат. Как починить?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что без переменной окружения: "SystemRoot=C:\\Windows" функции получения ip по имени работать не хотят.